# SQL: why is the HAVING clause rejected in this case?

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, having

the used table is here:

http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SUM_and_COUNT

There's a thing I can't understand. If I use this:

```
select continent, count(name)
from world
group by continent
having population >= 10000000
```

They say Unknown column 'population' in 'having clause'. But this other query is considered fine:

```
select continent
from world
group by continent
having sum(population) >= 100000000
```

Why? Why here the population column is recognized and on the first query is not?

Comment: Aggregate should be there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax for HAVING clause is:

```
SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name
HAVING aggregate_function(column_name) operator value;
```

There have to be some aggregate function (or already aggregated column) after HAVING.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing this is MySQL, since other DBMS will throw a different error (e.g SQL Server `Column 'world.population' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`, or Posgresql: `column "world.population" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`)

MySQL is slightly different and [extends the GROUP BY and HAVING clauses](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html), the docs state:

> A similar MySQL extension applies to the HAVING clause. In standard SQL, a query that includes a GROUP BY clause cannot refer to nonaggregated columns in the HAVING clause that are not named in the GROUP BY clause. A MySQL extension permits references to such columns to simplify calculations. This extension assumes that the nongrouped columns will have the same group-wise values. Otherwise, the result is indeterminate.

So the absence of an aggregate function, and because `population` is not in the group by clause, MySQL assumes you are using a column alias, and there is no column with an alias of `population`, therefore you get an unkown column error.

For example, if you give your column an alias of `population` the query compiles:

```
select continent, count(name) as population
from world
group by continent
having population >= 10000000
```

And is the semantic equivalent of

```
select continent, count(name) as population
from world
group by continent
having count(name) >= 10000000
```

---

I am not sure of your exact criteria, but I suspect you either want

**Continents with a population over 1,000,0000 and a count of countries in those continents**

```
select continent, count(name) as Countries
from world
group by continent
having sum(population) >= 10000000
```

Or

**A count of countries in each continent where the country has a population over 1,000,000**

```
select continent, count(name) as Countries
from world
where population >= 10000000 
group by continent;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can solve your issue:

```
select continent, count(name)
from world
where population >= 10000000 
group by continent
```

Here you exclude the rows with population less than 10000000 before aggregation.